# How to set the circle position inside the ColorSpectrum Corresponding to given Color in UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

what i have Tried is?

```
ColorSpectrum cs=new ColorSpectrum();
cs.width=280;
cs.height=280;
```

For my case,I have Color like this #FFF5F5F5.I want to set the circle position inside the ColorSpectrum Corresponding to this color?Can anyone help me ,how to write code for this?
I don't Know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly define the currently selected color by setting `ColorSpectrum.Color` (the circle will also change accordingly).

If you want to know how to convert Hash color value to `Windows.UI.Color` class, you can use the `ColorHelper` class in `CommunityToolkit`.

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var color = "#FFF5F5F5".ToColor();
    MyColorSpectrum.Color = color;
}
```

If you want to see how the `ToColor()` method is implemented, here is the [source code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/e383eeadb4bdcf07dcca4e2768f806eb2ef732f7/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp/Helpers/ColorHelper.cs)

In addition, I tested the color value of `#FFF5F5F5`, it is not very obvious, you can change a color (such as `#FFA322F3`) to observe whether this code takes effect.

---

**Update**

`ColorSpectrum` does not provide an option to control lightness separately. You need to create a Slider and adjust `ColorSpectrum.HsvColor.Value` separately.

**xaml**

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <ColorSpectrum Width="280" Height="280" x:Name="MyColorPanel" ColorChanged="MyColorPanel_ColorChanged"/>
    <Slider ValueChanged="ColorPickerSlider_ValueChanged" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" x:Name="MySlider"/>
    <Button Content="Click Me!" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**xaml.cs**

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var color = "#FF020202".ToColor();
    MyColorPanel.Color = color;
    var light = MyColorPanel.HsvColor.Z*100;
    MySlider.Value = light;
}

private void MyColorPanel_ColorChanged(ColorSpectrum sender, ColorChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var hsv = MyColorPanel.HsvColor;
    var c = args.NewColor;
    var o = args.OldColor;
    Debug.WriteLine(MyColorPanel.Color.ToString());
}

private void ColorPickerSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var color = MyColorPanel.HsvColor;
    color.Z = (float)(e.NewValue/100.0);
    MyColorPanel.HsvColor = color;
    Debug.WriteLine(MyColorPanel.Color.ToString());
}
```

`HsvColor` and `Color` will affect each other, we can change the lightness by modifying `HsvColor.Z`, and change the color in disguise.

Thanks.

Comment: If I set the color(#FF020202) like this.After setting the color,When I click inside the colorSpectrum,the ColorChange Event gives unexpected results (i.e.,NewColor from args).can u please check where ever you click inside the ColorSpectrum ,any one of RGB color must be 255.Then how can i set Color like this #FF020202

Comment: In `ColorSpectrum`, you also see that it does not have black color area. The black here is controlled using lightness (Value). When you set the color to black, it means that the lightness is minimized. After that, when you adjust `ColorSpectrum` selected value again, because the lightness has not changed, so the result of black is still calculated. Therefore, it is recommended to use the complete `ColorPicker` for color operations. Because `ColorPicker` provides a control bar for controlling lightness.

Comment: I don't want to use color picker because i need to add additional features..So that i have write it as a separate component..Is there any other way?